# Не правильная кодировка данных сертификата

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio, строки

Когда считываю с AndroidCAStore сертификаты, и хочу вывести информацию на экран, вся информация на русском выводить в виде кракозябр. Я перепробовал различные кодировки для того чтобы привести в наглядный вид, но итог везде один. В специфических кодировках иногда высвечивались русские буквы но даже полностью нормально слово он показать не мог.
методы вида к сожалению тоже не помогают. Что самое интересно, если открыть сертификат на компьютере(Windows 7), то все данные отображают корректно.  В чем может быть причина?

```
new String(original.getBytes("UTF-16BE"), "UTF-8");
```

[image: Не правильная кодировка сертификата]

Comment: Есть предположение, что вы неправильно пытаетесь достать свойства сертификата (они там с разделителями храняться), поэтомк просто байты непрочитать.
Поглядите здесь http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/DisplaypropertiesofX509Certificate.htm

Comment: Я считываю данные вот так certificate.getSubjectDN().getName() Только он не читает кириллицу...

Comment: Вы уверены что среда куда вы выводите готова отображать UTF8?

Comment: Ну да, всё дело происходит в Android. Вывести в логи или же отобразить в TextView я думаю можно.

Comment: а если попробовать посимвольно разобрать как здесь - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6230386/5292979?

Comment: Тестируя на реальном устройстве увидел такую картину http://joxi.ru/V2VLdRBI3eDwrv а это уже UTF-16 и он в онлайн декодере без проблем перевелся. Как мне на реально вытащить именно эти символы, т.к. когда делаю certificate.getSubjectDN().getName() получаю то что и раньше. С перебором символов не прокатило :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой код у меня получился чтобы исправить данную проблему.
Там где в сертификате используется кириллица, используется BMPString. У меня он почему-то приходил с подгулявшими(левыми байтами), поэтому через стандартные средства он перекодировался плохо, всё сбивалось. Поэтому пришлось написать свой метод, в который мы отдаём байты нашей BMPString строки.

```
   private static String decodeBMPString(byte[] bmpString) {
    if (bmpString.length % 2 != 0) {
        return "Bad string";
    }
    int len = bmpString.length;
    if (len > 2 && bmpString[len - 1] == 0 && bmpString[len - 2] == 0) {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[len - 2];
        System.arraycopy(bmpString, 0, tmp, 0, len - 2);
        bmpString = tmp;
    }
    StringBuilder decodeString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        char symbol;
        if (bmpString[i] > 4) {
            symbol = (char) bmpString[i];
            decodeString.append(symbol);
            --i;
        } else {
            symbol = (char) ((bmpString[i] << 8) + bmpString[i + 1]);
            decodeString.append(symbol);
        }
    }
    return decodeString.toString();
}
```

Метод вызываю вот так

```
private void getSubjectCN(Principal subject) {
    return decodeBMPString(subject.toString().getBytes());
}
```